# console.logs are not showing on browsers console but showing on my terminal

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just started learning React.js, and I'm doing very simple tests in a React project using Next.js.

I noticed that `console.log()` aren't showing up on any browser's console tab, but it's showing on the VS Code terminal instead. That won't be useful at all in future projects, I'd like to see it normally on the browser...

Here's the simple test:

```
export const Page = ()=> {

  console.log('Hello, World');

  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

After saving the changes and running "npm run dev", nothing appears on the console (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera...), not even error or warnings, but on VS Code terminal it's there:

```
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 976 ms (512 modules)
Hello, World
```

I can see `console.log` messages using JavaScript normally.
The Next.js project was initiated with default settings.
I already turned off all the browser extensions, created a new Next app, but same issue. I'm using npm `-v 9.6.7`.

I also looked for topics related, but I haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, in the `app` directory (the latest way of setting up routes), by default, Next.js uses [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components), where the JSX gets compiled to "pure HTML" and sent to the browser (with no additional JavaScript, that `console.log` in your case). This is for better performance, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#why-server-components):

> Server Components allow developers to better leverage server infrastructure. For example, large dependencies that previously would impact the JavaScript bundle size on the client can instead **remain entirely on the server**, leading to improved performance. They make writing a React application feel similar to PHP or Ruby on Rails, but with the power and flexibility of React for templating UI.

To be able to execute JavaScript script on the browser, you should add `"use client"` at the top, to make it a [Client Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components):

```js
"use client"; // This is a client component 

export default function Card() {
  console.log("Hello") // I will get this log on the browser, and also on the server while rendring

  return <></>;
}
```

---

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and corrections you made, I really appreciate it! It finally worked for me here :) And I also understood more about how Server and Client Components work in Next.js. It was a great help!